# Redshift UDF For Table Name?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

Can you use a Python UDF in Redshift to dynamically set a table name? Our tables are named like this: table_REGION_YYYYQQ

Based on what date/region parameters a user passes to the query through our internal ETL tools, I want to adjust the underlying table names. However, returning a table name as a string doesn't seem to work.

Are there any work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Amazon Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) says:

> You can create a custom user-defined scalar function (UDF) to implement non-SQL processing based on a Python program.

So, the UDF can be used to calculate values but cannot be used to call SQL functions (eg commands to ALTER table attributes).

While PostgreSQL has an `eval()` function that can run SQL commands from a string, this is not supported in Amazon Redshift.